# Memoir header problem with \chapter*

Tags: header-footer, memoir

I'm using memoir, when I use `\chapter*` the header is copied from the previous section.

How can I fix that?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\copypagestyle{ruledsmallhd}{ruled}
\makeevenhead{ruledsmallhd}{\footnotesize\scshape\leftmark}{}{}
\makeoddhead{ruledsmallhd}{}{}{\footnotesize\scshape\rightmark}
\makeheadrule{ruledsmallhd}{0px}{0px}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\pagestyle{ruledsmallhd}

\cleardoublepage
\maxtocdepth{subsection}
\tableofcontents

\cleardoublepage
\chapter*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does your Introduction have Roman page numbers?

Comment: Why don't you use `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter`. Is there any reason why the *Introduction* should not be in the TOC? Using `\frontmatter` disables numbering and `\chapter{Introduction} will be in the ToC automatically, no need for tricks

Comment: @egreg: I don't know, should it? :)

Comment: @AymanElmasry My suggestion is that it should simply be a numbered chapter in the main matter.

Comment: @daleif I understand now, this would have been useful if I wanted an unnumbered chapter in the main matter. `\frontmatter` `\mainmatter` works just fine in this particular case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need of any special trick:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\copypagestyle{ruledsmallhd}{ruled}
\makeevenhead{ruledsmallhd}{\footnotesize\scshape\leftmark}{}{}
\makeoddhead{ruledsmallhd}{}{}{\footnotesize\scshape\rightmark}
\makeheadrule{ruledsmallhd}{0pt}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\pagestyle{ruledsmallhd}

\cleardoublepage
\maxtocdepth{subsection}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}

\lipsum

\mainmatter

\chapter{Let the fun begin}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]